# Why sqlalchemy ignore load_only?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the User model with relationship to posts.

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    posts = relationship('Post',secondary=user2post, lazy="dynamic")

class Post(Base):
    ...
    mark = Column(Integer)
```

I need to get all marks of posts from user. For this I write the following query: `session.query(User).get(same_id).posts.options(load_only("mark")).all()` and it return me list of Posts with all data as if I did not write `posts.options(load_only("mark"))`.
Version of sqlalchemy is 1.2.11.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The query you've presented would result in `Post` instances with only the mark (and primary key) loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their documentation about *Deferred Column Loading*:

> This feature allows particular columns of a table be loaded only upon direct access, instead of when the entity is queried using Query.

After the query happens, accessing the returned posts do counts as "direct access" so the orm will fetch the deferred columns

Comment: Okey, and how I can get only needed columns?

Comment: Been a while since I used SQLAlchemy, but I think it must be something like `session.query(User.same_id, Post.mark).join(User.posts).all()`. That will get you tuples instead of objects.